# How to select elements of a tensor along a specific axis in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor `t` of shape `(2, 3, 4)`

```
t = tf.random.normal((2, 3, 4))

<tf.Tensor: id=55, shape=(2, 3, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.86664855, -0.32786712, -0.9517335 ,  0.989722  ],
        [-0.25011402, -0.35941386, -1.0808105 ,  0.60205466],
        [ 0.07523973, -0.6512919 ,  1.3695312 , -1.5043781 ]],

       [[ 0.33990988, -0.17364176,  0.72955394, -0.7119293 ],
        [ 0.4013214 ,  0.5653289 ,  1.4327284 ,  1.2687784 ],
        [-1.1986154 ,  1.3783301 ,  1.714094  ,  0.49866664]]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

and a set of indices `idx` of size `(2, 3)` with values that index along the last dimension  of `t`

```
idx = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randint(4, size=(2, 3)))

<tf.Tensor: id=56, shape=(2, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[2, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 1]])>
```

How can I extract the elements of `t` along it's last dimension at the indices specified by `idx`? The result should be the following tensor of shape `(2, 3)`.

```
<tf.Tensor: id=57, shape=(2, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[-0.9517335, -1.0808105, -1.5043781],
       [0.33990988,  1.2687784,  1.3783301]])>
```

I have been trying and failing with regular indexing

```
t[:, :, idx]  # error
t[..., idx]   # error
```

and [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/gather) / [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd)

```
tf.gather(t, idx, axis=2)  # has shape (2, 3, 2, 3)
tf.gather_nd(t, idx)       # has shape (2, )
```

neither of which seem to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Think again about what you are trying to achieve. What are the indices of the elements you are trying to extract for the first and second axes? From your example, it seems that you are thinking about flattening the first two dimension so `t` is (6,4) and  extracting the elements whose first dimension indices are 0:6 and the second dimension indices are given by `idx`.

To achieve this, you have to actually specify the indices for all dimensions. We can start by reshaping `t` to be 2D:

```
t_2d=tf.reshape(t,[-1,tf.shape(t)[-1]])

<tf.Tensor: id=55, shape=(6, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.86664855, -0.32786712, -0.9517335 ,  0.989722  ],
       [-0.25011402, -0.35941386, -1.0808105 ,  0.60205466],
       [ 0.07523973, -0.6512919 ,  1.3695312 , -1.5043781 ],
       [ 0.33990988, -0.17364176,  0.72955394, -0.7119293 ],
       [ 0.4013214 ,  0.5653289 ,  1.4327284 ,  1.2687784 ],
       [-1.1986154 ,  1.3783301 ,  1.714094  ,  0.49866664]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Now, we'll specify the indices of the first axis:

```
idx_0=tf.reshape(tf.range(t_2d.shape[0]),idx.shape)

<tf.Tensor: id=62, shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]], dtype=int32)>
```

Join the indices of the first and second axes as expected by `tf.gather_nd`:

```
indices=tf.stack([idx_0,idx],axis=-1)

<tf.Tensor: id=64, shape=(2, 3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[0, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[3, 0],
        [4, 3],
        [5, 1]]], dtype=int32)>
```

And finally:

```
tf.gather_nd(t_2d,indices)

<tf.Tensor: id=66, shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.9517335 , -1.0808105 , -1.5043781 ],
       [ 0.33990988,  1.2687784 ,  1.3783301 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
def tf_select_along_axis(arr, selecting_ixs, axis: int):
    """ Select the given indices along the given axis. 
    :param arr: A N-dimensional tensor of shape (D[0], ..., D[axis], ..., D[N])
    :param selecting_ixs: A N-1 dimensional tensor of shape (D[0], ... D[axis-1], D[axis+1], ... D[N]) int32 which selects elements along axis
    :param axis: The axis along which you're selecting.
    """
    ixs = [tf.broadcast_to(tf.range(arr.shape[d])[(slice(None),) + (None,) * (axis - i)], selecting_ixs.shape) for i, d in enumerate(range(axis))] \
          + [selecting_ixs] \
          + [tf.broadcast_to(tf.range(arr.shape[d])[(slice(None),) + (None,) * (axis - i)], selecting_ixs.shape) for i, d in
             enumerate(range(axis + 1, len(arr.shape)), start=axis + 1)]
    ixs_nd = tf.reshape(tf.stack(ixs, axis=-1), (-1, len(arr.shape)))
    return tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(arr, ixs_nd), selecting_ixs.shape)
```

Which can be demonstrated by

```
def test_select_along_axis():
    arr = tf.random.uniform((20, 30, 40), seed=1234)
    argmax = tf.argmax(arr, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
    maxval = tf.reduce_max(arr, axis=1)
    assert np.array_equal(maxval, tf_select_along_axis(arr, argmax, axis=1).numpy())
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `tensorflow>=2.4` you can take advantage of `tf.experimental.numpy.take_along_axis`

```
tf.squeeze(tf.experimental.numpy.take_along_axis(t, idx[..., tf.newaxis], axis=-1))
```